# Как выбрать 2 ключа и их значения?

Tags: json, парсер

Есть JSON со множеством значений (порядка 80 ключей):

```
{
...
  "london": {
    "name": "value"
  },
  "moscow": {
    "name": "value"
  },
  "berlin": {
    "name": "value"
  }
...
}
```

Как из него выбрать ключ, например, 'london' и 'berlin', и получить следующее:

```
{
...
  "london": {
    "name": "value"
  }
  "berlin": {
    "name": "value"
  }
...
}
```

То есть, из 80 ключей получить только 2-3, которые я передам в строке, а так же их значения.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var data = {
  "london": {
    "name": "value1"
  },
  "katmandu": {
    "name": "value2"
  },
  "moscow": {
    "name": "value3"
  },
  "berlin": {
    "name": "value4"
  }
};

function getSubobject(obj, keys) {
  return keys.reduce((acc, i) => { 
    if (i in obj) 
      acc[i] = obj[i]; 
    return acc;
  }, {});
}

var subdata = getSubobject(data, ["london", "berlin"]);
console.log(subdata);
```